# Choose active page in Visio

Tags: excel, visio, vba

Edited:  I didn't phrase this very will..  I am trying to open Visio (working) and then open a page in the document of my choosing.  Thanks

```
Dim FName As String
Dim VsApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set VsApp = GetObject(, "Visio.Application")
If VsApp Is Nothing Then
Set VsApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
If VsApp Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Can't connect to Visio"
Exit Sub
End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0

FName = "C:\myfile.vsd"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c2")) Is Nothing Then
VsApp.Documents.Open FName
VsAppPage = "mypage"
Cancel = True
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("c4")) Is Nothing Then
VsApp.Documents.Open FName
vsPage = "mypage2"
VsApp.ActivePage = vsPage
Cancel = True
End if
```

But this is code it trying to rename the active page.  I would like it to select the page name in quotes.

Comment: Try to do this in the else section `activePageName = VsApp.ActivePage` before you assign the new name ofcorse!!

Comment: Good idea, but this seems to get the active page name.  I am hoping to assign and goto the active page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
VsApp.ActiveWindow.Page = vsPage
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
VsApp.ActiveWindow.Page = VsApp.Documents.Open(FName).Pages(vsPage)
```

Comment: I would expect the latter to work, except you need to use the set statement (remember, when the left hand side of the = operator is an object, VBA just sets the default property - in this case the page's name).  So try "set VsApp.ActiveWindow.Page = VsApp.Documents.Open(FName).Pages(vsPage)"

Comment: Using Set will not work.  I had a look and the Page property on a Visio Window object is a string, so either of my suggestions should work, since VBA will cast a page object to string, since the default property on the page is the page name.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using VsApp.ActiveWindow.Page = vsPage and that worked!