# Change active page of Visio object in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, object, visio

I have an Excel document in which I inserted Visio object. It has a few pages, each page has a specific model and according to some checkboxes in excel I want to choose a specific page, so when I print the excel, it will have specific model from visio. All this should do via VBA code that will be trigered by checkmark. The Vision object is embeded in excel, I dont want to link an external document.
So far I managed to activate the visio object, with this code:

```
Set visioObj = Worksheets("Document").OLEObjects("objekt 4")
visioObj.Activate
```

But I can't figure out, how to change the active page.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thank you.

I tried `Application.ActivePage` and `visioObj.ActiveWindow.Page = visioObj.Pages("Strana-3")` with no success.

Comment: `visioObj.Pages("Strana-3").Activate` maybe?

Comment: It send error '438', object doesn't support this property or method. I am starting to worry that what I want to do is impossible. I could only find events that works with that oleobject as whole (add new, delete it, duplicate it, ...) but not make changes specific to that kind of document (in this case, visio type document). But then, I have no idea what would be better approach to what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646937/choose-active-page-in-visio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose active page in Visio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646937/choose-active-page-in-visio)

Comment: Tried:
Set visioObj = Worksheets("Document").OLEObjects("objekt 4")
visioObj.Activate
vsPage = "Strana-3"
visioObj.ActiveWindow.Page = vsPage
But still the same error 438.
The other option from your link that you define path to vsd file I cant use since I work with embeded object in excel.

Comment: Found a solution elsewhere. What I needed to use was:
visioObj.Object.Application.ActiveWindow.Page = vsPage